# sudo login using plink executing by a batch file (mind blogging)

Tags: unix, batch-file, dos, putty

Here is what I wanna do... connent to a remote unix server from plink which is executed in a batch file, to run a script of other user name(as sudo user). I tried this.

```
@echo off
set /p id="Enter Unix Login ID: " %=% 
set /p pwd="Enter Password: " %=% 
cls
del jobInfo_error.txt
plink -l %id% -pw %pwd% Server0 "sudo su - user222" 2>>JobInfo_error.txt
plink -l %id% -pw %pwd% Server0 "/export/home/user222/user222_unix_works.ksh" 2>>JobInfo_error.txt
start notepad JobInfo_error.txt
```

In the above code i login as `user000` and then i wanna sudo login as `user222` and run the script `user222_unix_works.ksh`. The privilege for executing and writing is only given to `user222` and i dont wanna change it.

here is why i think I am not geting the result I want, the first plink command `plink -l %id% -pw %pwd% Server0 "sudo su - user222" 2>>JobInfo_error.txt` is execute but the session is terminated and when the second runs i login as `user000` and fails to execute.

is there a way to achive this?
here is the error in JobInfo_error.txt

```
  bash: /export/home/user222/user222_unix_works.ksh: Permission denied
```

oh 2 more things i cannot directly login as `user222`

and i can execute any file for which `user000` has privileges. i.e if i simple run with

```
plink -l %id% -pw %pwd% Server0 "/export/home/user000/user000.ksh"
```

it works.

Comment: Those two ssh connections are totally separate. Why do you think that changing of the user account during the first session has any effect on the second connection? Easiest would probably be to use a completely different approach: just make a single connection and use it to start a native shell script located on that target system. In that script you can change the effective user id and then do whatever you want.

Comment: ok, but in this approach i would have to hard code the password into the script which i dont want.

Comment: No, that is not required. The sudo utility can be used more advanced: you can grant access to a very specific command to a single user account that can be executed without specifying a password. Since storing and transmitting of passwords always is a security issue you should consider that approach.

Comment: hmm im not Root here and i dont have privileges. how would it be? `plink -l %id% -pw %pwd% Server0 "/export/home/user000/user000.ksh"` where `user000.ksh` has `sudo su - user222 nopasswd /export/home/user222/user222_unix_works.ksh`

Comment: Ah, ok, that is something else then, indeed. You need root permissions to setup the sudo utility once to grant a command execution.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, no, sorry. The problem is that you cannot chain the commands, since you cannot interactively provide the password in that case. Maybe a tunnel can help here? Why can't you login as user `user222`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54840/discussion-between-arkascha-and-kaze-sujan).

Comment: Another idea would be to install the final command once on the target system and use setuid bits in its file permission to execute it under the user of user `user222`.

Comment: not sure how to do that... and im in office network so i cant join you in chat unfortunately.

Comment: The `setuid` bit on unixoid file systems allows you to setup a file that can be executed by one user but actually runs under the effective user id of another user. This would be what you ask for here: you could prepare such a script once, set its ownership to `user222` and set its `setuid` bit. Then when you login as user `user000` and execute the script it would be executed effectively as user `user222`. The problem is that all modern linux distributions have _disabled_ the setuid bit _for shell scripts_. The workaround is here: http://www.tuxation.com/setuid-on-shell-scripts.html

Comment: how about: `plink -l %id% -pw %pwd% Server0 sudo su - user222 -c 'export/home/user222/user222_nix_works.ksh' 2>>JobInfo_error.txt'` ?

Comment: Tried that bro gives me error `Plink error: Command not found on remote host(Exit code 127)`